# Add a new function .m file to MATLAB permanently

Tags: matlab, function, path

I'd like to add a new function to my Matlab so I can use it from everywhere permanently. I added the new path to the folder where I put this new function .m file. When I call this function from anywhere else, the current location moves to the folder where I have this function. How can I use the function but stay at the current folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use [`addpath`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html)?

Comment: I tried this as well. But the problem is when I call the function the current folder also changes to the folder where the function file is. I'd like to stay at the current folder but just call the function only.

Comment: If you have correctly added the folder containing your function to MATLAB's search path the only reason MATLAB will change directories on calling the function is if you are using `cd` in the function and not returning properly. Being able to call a function without changing the current directory is the whole point of MATLAB's search path.

Comment: @Joseph The behavior you describe is not in line with anything I have  ever seen in Matlab. Please edit your question to provide more detailed information, such as the contents of the function and how the function is called.

Comment: Thank you. I still cannot solve the issue. Actually I am trying to use mmread (from File Exchange) to read my video file in the current folder. What I'd like to do is to call mmread from somewhere and then read the video in the current folder.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for such weird behavior is that inside [mmread](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread/content/mmread.m), the script changes the current folder by calling `cd`:

```
currentdir = pwd;
try
    if ~ispc
        cd(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))); % FFGrab searches for AVbin in the current directory
    end
...
end
if ~ispc
    cd(currentdir);
end
```

When the script runs without error, it should return to your current folder before exiting. But if something goes wrong, it may abort without restoring the `currentdir`. So I think you'd better spend time to figure out what's going wrong with the script instead of trying to restrict the script in the current folder.

Comment: Thanks. Actually when I put mmread at the same folder where I have a video file, it runs correctly. So I think when I call mmread the video file name is not sent correctly. I'm not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to go to your `Documents` directory, where you should see a folder called `Matlab`. If you put an `.m` file in there, it will always be available, even if you reinstall Matlab.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand that it should work. But the issue I cannot solve is that the current folder moving to the folder where I have this function. I'd like to stay at the current folder but just call the function only.